# Element-wise variance of an iterator

Tags: statistics, julia

What's a numerically-stable way of taking the variance of an iterator elementwise? As an example, I would like to do something like

```
var((rand(4,2) for i in 1:10))
```

and get back a `(4,2)` matrix which is the variance in each coefficient. This throws an error using Julia's Base `var`. Is there a package that can handle this? Or an easy (and storage-efficient) way to do this using the Base Julia function? Or does one need to be developed on its own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went ahead and implemented a Welford algorithm to calculate this:

```
# Welford algorithm
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance
function componentwise_meanvar(A;bessel=true)
  x0 = first(A)
  n = 0
  mean = zero(x0)
  M2 = zero(x0)
  delta = zero(x0)
  delta2 = zero(x0)
  for x in A
    n += 1
    delta .= x .- mean
    mean .+= delta./n
    delta2 .= x .- mean
    M2 .+= delta.*delta2
  end
  if n < 2
    return NaN
  else
    if bessel
      M2 .= M2 ./ (n .- 1)
    else
      M2 .= M2 ./ n
    end
    return mean,M2
  end
end
```

A few other algorithms are implemented [in DiffEqMonteCarlo.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqMonteCarlo.jl/blob/master/src/analysis.jl) as well. I'm surprised I couldn't find a library for this, but maybe will refactor this out someday.

Answer (score 0):

*See update below for a numerically stable version*

Another method to calculate this:

```
srand(0)   # reset random for comparing across implementations

moment2var(t) = (t[3]-t[2].^2./t[1])./(t[1]-1)
foldfunc(x,y) = (x[1]+1,x[2].+y,x[3].+y.^2)

moment2var(foldl(foldfunc,(0,zeros(1,1),zeros(1,1)),(rand(4,2) for i=1:10)))
```

Gives:

```
4×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0848123  0.0643537
 0.0715945  0.0900416
 0.111934   0.084314 
 0.0819135  0.0632765
```

Similar to:

```
srand(0)   # reset random for comparing across implementations

# naive component-wise application of `var` function
map(var,zip((rand(4,2) for i=1:10)...))
```

which is the non-iterator version (or offline version in CS terminology).

This method is based on calculation of variance from mean and sum-of-squares. `moment2var` and `foldfunc` are just a helper functions, but it fits in one-line without them.

Comments:

- Speedwise, this should be pretty good as well. Perhaps, StaticArrays and initializing the `foldl`'s `v0` with the correct `eltype` of the iterator would save even more time.
- Benchmarking gave **5x** speed advantage (and better memory usage) over `componentwise_meanvar` (from another answer) on a sample input.
- Using `moment2meanvar(t)=(t[2]./t[1],(t[3]-t[2].^2./t[1])./(t[1]-1)‌​)` gives both mean and variance like `componentwise_meanvar`.
- As @ChrisRackauckas noted, this method suffers from numerical instability when number of elements to sum is large.

--- UPDATE with variant of method ---

A little abstraction of the question asks for a way to do a `foldl` (and `reduce`,`foldr`) on an iterator returning a matrix, element-wise and retaining shape. To do so, we can define an assisting function `mfold` which takes a folding-function and makes it fold matrices element-wise. Define it as follows:

```
mfold(f) = (x,y)->[f(t[1],t[2]) for t in zip(x,y)]
```

For this specific problem of variance, we can define the component-wise fold functions, and a final function to combine the moments into the variance (and mean if wanted). The code:

```
ff(x,y) = (x[1]+1,x[2]+y,x[3]+y^2)          # fold and collect moments
moment2var(t) = (t[3]-t[2]^2/t[1])/(t[1]-1) # calc variance from moments
moment2meanvar(t) = (t[2]./t[1],(t[3]-t[2].^2./t[1])./(t[1]-1))
```

We can see `moment2meanvar` works on a single vector as follows:

```
julia> moment2meanvar(foldl(ff,(0.0,0.0,0.0),[1.0,2.0,3.0]))
(2.0, 1.0)
```

Now to matrix-ize it using `foldm` (using `.`-notation):

```
moment2var.(foldl(mfold(ff),fill((0,0,0),(4,2)),(rand(4,2) for i=1:10)))
```

@ChrisRackauckas noted this is not numerically stable, and another method (detailed in Wikipedia) is better. Using `foldm` this could be implemented as:

```
# better fold function compensating the sums for stability
ff2(x,y) = begin 
  delta=y-x[2]
  mean=x[2]+delta/(x[1]+1)
  return (x[1]+1,mean,x[3]+delta*(y-mean)) 
end

# combine the collected information for the variance (and mean)
m2var(t) = t[3]/(t[1]-1)
m2meanvar(t) = (t[2],t[3]/(t[1]-1))
```

Again we have:

```
m2var.(foldl(mfold(ff2),fill((0,0.0,0.0),(4,2)),(rand(4,2) for i=1:10)))
```

Giving the same results (perhaps a little more accurately).

Comment: Is this method numerically stable for large N? Where could I read about it? And did you test on v0.6? I used a lot of broadcast in mine, so it will suck on v0.5.

Comment: Tested on v0.6 (my v0.5 is deleted b/c of disk-space shortage). The method is basic probability theorem: Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2 (any textbook should have it).

Comment: Yes, but isn't that method [very numerically unstable?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) I thought that's what you're doing but if so, that doesn't work for large N.

Comment: That is true. Depending on number of elements in sum, and the numerical accuracy requirements, this might not be a good way to go.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas The updated section has the more numerically stable method from Wikipedia. Didn't benchmark it yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Or an easy (and storage-efficient) way to do this using the Base Julia function?

Out of curiosity, why is the standard solution of using `var` along the external dimension not good for you?

```julia
julia> var(cat(3,(rand(4,2) for i in 1:10)...),3)
4×2×1 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.08847    0.104799 
 0.0946243  0.0879721
 0.105404   0.0617594
 0.0762611  0.091195
```

Obviously, I'm using `cat` here, which clearly is not very storage efficient, just so I can use the Base Julia function and your original generator syntax as per your question. But you could make this storage efficient as well, if you initialise your random values directly on a preallocated array of size (4,2,10), so that's not really an issue here.

Or did I misunderstand your question?

---

**EDIT - benchmark in response to comments**

```julia
function standard_var(Y, A)
  for i in 1 : length(A)
    Y[:,:,i], = next(A,i);
  end
  var(Y,3)
end

function testit()
  A = (rand(4,2) for i in 1:10000);
  Y = Array{Float64, 3}(4,2,length(A));
  @time componentwise_meanvar(A); # as defined in Chris's answer above
  @time standard_var(Y, A)        # standard variance + using preallocation
  @time var(cat(3, A...), 3);     # standard variance without preallocation
  return nothing
end
```

```julia
julia> testit()
  0.004258 seconds (10.01 k allocations: 1.374 MiB)
  0.006368 seconds (49.51 k allocations: 2.129 MiB)
  5.954470 seconds (50.19 M allocations: 2.989 GiB, 71.32% gc time)
```

Comment: "But you could make this storage efficient if you initialise your random values directly on a preallocated array of size (4,2,10), so that's not really an issue here." That's exactly opposite of the truth. If you make the array, you have to use storage. If you use a generator, you can make it so that way the array is never fully in memory.

Comment: "Alternatively, you could adopt a sequential estimation approach for the variance, and make this part of a new iterator. This would be the most memory-efficient approach, and while it might still 'suffer' from numerical cancellation". No, this Welford algorithm (I got the idea by checking the Base code a few hours after asking the question) is sequential and numerically stable.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I've added a benchmark to clarify. Your Welford implementation does indeed perform _best_ (and consistent with `var` up to 15 sig. digits), but my point is if you want to use the Base function for consistency, then as long as you preallocate, the performance / storage penalty is comparable and more than acceptable. This is what you had _asked_ (i.e. "an easy and storage-efficient way to do this using the Base Julia function"). I interpreted your question as "without having to 'collect', as this is expensive in terms of storage", which is indeed true as shown by the third test.

Comment: " but my point is if you want to use the Base function for consistency, then as long as you preallocate, the performance / storage penalty is comparable and more than acceptable. This is what you had asked": yeah, when I asked it, I assumed that there was a way to directly use the generator in the Base var. Turns out I wasn't dumb and you do have to allocate the whole thing to use the Base var function, so I guess I just started by asking the wrong question. I'm surprised something simple like that isn't in Base though. It's just a wiki translation